# Vector Space or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the functions $( c_1 + c_2 \sin^2x + c_3 \cos^2x)$ form a vector space. Find the basis.

My solution:
The set of all linear combinations of $\{1, \sin^2x, \cos^2x\}$ has been given.

So we can write any equation  $ c_1 + c_2 \sin^2x + c_3 \cos^2x$ in the form $ c_1 \sin^2x + c_1 \cos^2x + c_2 \sin^2x + c_3 \cos^2x$ 
Then we can rewrite this as $ a \sin^2x + b \cos^2x$
Assuming this is a vector space, I can say the basis is $\{\sin^2x, \cos^2x\}$ and the dimension is 2.

The condition for it to be a vector space is $ (c + d)(x + y) = cx + dx + cy + dy$ where x, y are the vectors and c, d are constants. If I put $\{\sin^2x, \cos^2x\}$ as x and y then the above equation simply becomes $c + d$. That is not a proof of being a vector space.

How do I actually use this prove that this is a vector space ?

Comment: You need to check your definitions. It looks to me as though you are trying to prove it is a space by showing it's a subspace of the vector space of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. OK, but then you need to show that (i) $0$ is in your set (ii) for all $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $u:=a+b\sin^2 x+ c\cos^2 x$, $v:=A+B\sin^2 x+ C\cos^2 x$ we have that $p\cdot u+ q\cdot v$ can be expressed as $\alpha+\beta\sin^2 x+\gamma\cos^2 x$.

Comment: To add to what ancient mathematician wrote, you also need to show that your proposed basis $\{\sin^2 x, \cos^2 x\}$ is linearly independent, i.e. $a \sin^2 x + b \sin^2 x = 0$ iff $a = b = 0$.

Comment: Just a quick note on your terminology: $c_1 + c_2 \sin^2 x + c_3 \cos^2 x$ etc. are not equations - there's no equals-sign, nothing is being equated. It's better to call them expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are working over the field $\Bbb R$.

Let $V$ be your set of functions. If $c_1+c_2\sin^2+c_3\cos^2,d_1+d_2\sin^2+d_3\cos^2\in V$, then their sum is$$c_1+d_1+(c_2+d_2)\sin^2+(c_3+d_3)\cos^2\in V.$$Also, if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, then$$\lambda(c_1+c_2\sin^2+c_3\cos^2)=\lambda c_1+\lambda c_2\sin^2+\lambda c_3\sin^2\in V.$$So, since $V\ne\emptyset$ (for instance, the null function is in $V$), $V$ is a vector space.

And *a* basis of $V$ (not *the* basis) is $\{\cos^2,\sin^2\}$, since it spans $V$ and it is linearly independent. So, you have indeed $\dim V=2$.